# Azure Virtual Machine Policy Not Starting on Pacific Hours

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, azure-virtual-machine

I am new to azure management, I have noticed that in our dev environment, our Virtual machine which is expected to turn on during pacific time working hours and turn off after. Currently it is no longer turning on automatically, I have to manually start the machine, but it still turns off after pacific hours. I wanted to know what policy should I look into, and if this behavior is expected in Production environment as well.

By the way, the virtual machine is used to house the integration runtime which connects to OnPrem data for our data factory pipelines.

Comment: Which way do you use to schedule to shutdown the VM? the auto-shutdown?

Comment: Nope, I believe there is a policy to shut down the VM automatically during non PST work hours.

Comment: So that you can try the [automation runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/start-runbooks).

Comment: Does it solve your problem? Or what do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the possible way as I know is that the Azure Automation runbook. There is a feature that can start and stop the VMs in the schedule. You can take a look at the [Start/Stop VMs during off-hours](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management). It manages VMs in any region, but can only be used in the same subscription as your Azure Automation account.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the very late response, after a long time, I was able to push this ansible code to production, based on my observation, the deployed VM did not shutdown. Looks like the policy is different when the environment is production. There may be a bigger limitation of the usage of VM. I no longer dug deeper and considered this resolved.